# How to SELECT other fields from the row with the MAX value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am new to Postgres, I used to work with MySQL.

My problem is simple, it is also never happens in MySQL. `t1` is my main table and `t2` holds the history of updates that occurred to a field in `t1` called status. So whenever an entry in `t1` changes it's status field, a new record is added to `t2` with the current timestamp and the new status value.

Now I want to to get the latest status and timestamp of a specific entry in `t1`, for example that with id *1271*. I can get the latest timestamp with the following query.

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.message,
  MAX(t2.creation_timestamp)
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table_1_id
WHERE t1.id = 1271
GROUP BY t1.id,t1.message
```

But when I try to also get the status of that specific row with the MAX timestamp.

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.message,
  t2.status,
  MAX(t2.creation_timestamp)
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table_1_id
WHERE t1.id = 1271
GROUP BY t1.id,t1.message
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: column "t2.status" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How can I get the status of the record with the MAX timestamp ?

Comment: Or maybe mysql is smart enough to understand that since the query will return one row from the MAX aggregate then it will return that other fields from that specific if they exist in the select. Anyway how to do it in Postgresql ?

Comment: Postgres would be smart enough if you define proper primary and foreign keys. See my answer

Answer (score 3):

Your query is rejected by Postgres because it's invalid SQL. The problem exists in MySQL as well, you were just lucky so far because MySQL chooses to return random values rather then rejecting the invalid group by (you might want to read [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/) or [this](http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html) for details on the MySQL implementation)

The most efficient solution in Postgres is to use `distinct on ()`

```
SELECT distinct on (t1.id)
       t1.id,
       t1.message,
       t2.status,
       t2.creation_timestamp
FROM table_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table_1_id
WHERE t1.id = 1271
ORDER BY t1.id, t2.creation_timestamp DESC;
```

---

However, *if* `id` is defined as the primary key of `table_1` and there is a proper foreign key relationship between the two tables, Postgres **will** accept the partial group by as it knows that the `id` is unique.

```
psql (9.6.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> create table table_1 (id integer primary key, message text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> create table table_2 (table_1_id integer references table_1, status text, creation_timestamp timestamp);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=> insert into table_1
postgres-> values
postgres-> (1271, 'one'),
postgres-> (1272, 'two'),
postgres-> (1273, 'three');
INSERT 0 3

postgres=> insert into table_2
postgres-> values
postgres-> (1271, 'active', timestamp '2016-12-30 10:00:00'),
postgres-> (1271, 'active', timestamp '2016-12-30 11:00:00'),
postgres-> (1271, 'active', timestamp '2016-12-30 12:00:00'),
postgres-> (1272, 'active', timestamp '2016-12-30 11:00:00'),
postgres-> (1272, 'active', timestamp '2016-12-30 12:00:00'),
postgres-> (1273, 'active', timestamp '2016-12-30 13:00:00'),
postgres-> (1273, 'active', timestamp '2016-12-30 13:00:00');
INSERT 0 7

postgres=> SELECT
postgres->   t1.id,
postgres->   t1.message,
postgres->   MAX(t2.creation_timestamp)
postgres-> FROM table_1 t1
postgres-> LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table_1_id
postgres-> WHERE t1.id = 1271
postgres-> GROUP BY t1.id
postgres-> ;
  id  | message |         max
------+---------+---------------------
 1271 | one     | 2016-12-30 12:00:00
(1 row)
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7cfc8/1

Answer (score 1):

you should have latest status on table_1, you should not need it from table_2, you need only latest timestamp

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    t1.message, 
    t1.status, 
    tmax.creation_timestamp
from table_1 t1
left join (
    select table_1_id, MAX(creation_timestamp) creation_timestamp 
    from table_2 
    group by table_1_id
) tmax on tmax.table_1_id = t1.id
WHERE t1.id = 1271
```

Answer (score 0):

Join using subquery selecting max(creation_timestamp)

```
SELECT
 t1.id,
 t1.message,
 t2.status,
 t2.creation_timestamp
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table_1_id 
and t2.creation_timestamp = (SELECT MAX(creation_timestamp) 
from table_2 t3 where t1.id = t3.table_1_id ) 
WHERE t1.id = 1271
```

Comment: you missed that table_2 holds info of different ID's (table_1_id)

Comment: I still don't get what I missed. I just added additional condition to the join clause. What is wrong about it ? Join works as it worked before but instead of joining all timestamps it joins only the one which has tme max(creation_timestamp)

Comment: the select max() is wrong, must be grouped by table_1_id